# EXCEL VBA: How to filter on same column header across multiple worksheets

Tags: excel, vba, filter, automation

I'm trying to filter on a column labeled "Date" across 10 worksheets. The column "Date" may not be in the same column position for every worksheet.

Is there a macro or code I can use to filter on the "Date" column in one easy button push? Instead of going to each individual worksheet and filtering separately..

I would only be filtering on the same date for all worksheets. For example, if I wanted to filter on "9/3/2021", I would go to each worksheet and find the "Date" column and manually filter 10 times.

Comment: "Need help" ... Did you perhaps start with the macro recorder? Or similar questions on this site?

Comment: The issue I'm having with the macro recorder is that I would be using this workbook every day and filtering for different dates every day.

Comment: That's why I used the word "start"... you have to modify the resulting code, but it's a start. Also `Date` returns today's date.

Comment: Is the column headers on the same row in all the involved sheets? If yes, is it the first row? Are these 10 sheets all the workbook sheets?

Comment: Yes, the column headers are all on the first row. The 10 sheets are all of the workbook sheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you add two simple cells to one of your sheets containing the `header text` and the `value you want to filter` you can use the below code to achieve the intended result.

for example my header named `"Date"` so in my `first sheet` I wrote `"Date"` in `A3` and the date I want to filter into `A4`. just keep in mind that since we are searching for the `"Date"` header in `first row` either we should put our so called `Criteria Range` header in another row or since our search ends with first occurrence we can add the new header to one of the columns after our `original Date column`.

**Note:**

The `Criteria Range` table headers must be **exactly** like the target selection headers for this to work. so here I have one column and one header, and I only selected the Date column.

```
Sub Test()
Dim Rng As Range
    For i = 1 To 4
        With Sheets(i).Range("A1:Z1")
        Set Rng = .Find(What:="Date", _
                            After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                            MatchCase:=False)
            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                '################################# New Part ▼
                ' R will be the address of the found column in Range format (e.g. "F1")
                R = Rng.Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
                Dim rgData As Range, rgCriteria As Range

                ' rgCriteria is the two cells Criteria Range
                Set rgCriteria = Sheets(1).Range("A3:A4")

                ' these next two lines are adding the Date column range to rgData
                LastRow = Sheets(i).Cells(Rows.Count, Rng.Column).End(xlUp).Row
                Set rgData = Sheets(i).Range(Sheets(i).Range(R), Sheets(i).Cells(LastRow, Rng.Column))

                ' since I was disappointed in AutoFilter I used Advanced Filter and its even faster
                rgData.AdvancedFilter xlFilterInPlace, rgCriteria
                '################################# New Part ▲
            Else
                MsgBox "Nothing found"
            End If
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

That's All!

**References:**

○ - Thanks to [this Excel Macro Mastery channel video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0YNhxVu2a5s). make sure to watch it to get a better understanding of what I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

you can find the "Date" column (which I presume there is a row contains the word "Date") by searching that row (e.g. first row of each sheet) for the word "Date". then you can give the column number to your filtration sub and get your filtering result.

**1st Way**

```
Sub Test()
    For i = 1 To 10
        For j = 1 To 50
            If Worksheets(i).Cells(1, j).Value = "Date" Then
                ' here goes your filtration procedure on j column
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

which `i` is the number of worksheets and `j` is the found column (in first 50 columns)

**2nd Way (Faster Way)**

Using `Range.Find` which suggested by @BigBen because:

> Looping cell-by-cell is slow and inefficient

```
Sub Test()
Dim Rng As Range
    For i = 1 To 5
        With Sheets(i).Range("A1:Z1")
        Set Rng = .Find(What:="Date", _
                            After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                            MatchCase:=False)
            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                ' here goes your filtration procedure on (Rng.Column)
            Else
                MsgBox "Nothing found"
            End If
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

which `i` is the number of worksheets and `Rng.Column` is the found column (in A1:Z1 range)

**References**:

1. [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) page for `Range.Find` method
2. there is another Microsoft Docs Page if you want
   to use [Application.Match](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.match) method

Comment: @BigBen It's not going to be any faster or anything I suppose but I added `Range.Find`. Thanks

Comment: well the reason I used second `for` was because first it was easier and second I forgotten the use of `Sheets(i).Range("Something")` for the `find` function and I was thinking the `find` function can't search through different sheets XD My bad, and thanks again :)

Comment: How do you write the filter procedure? For example, if I wanted to filter on "9/1/2021" date for that Date column? For the second way. I wrote Rng.Column.AutoFilter field:="9/1/2021" and getting invalid qualifier. Sorry I'm new to VBA

Comment: @SJK "9/1/2021" is a string. It must be a date (or a `Long`, as Excel keeps date). So, you should declare a variable as date, giving to it a `Date` value or you should convert it in the place you put the string: `CDate("9/1/2021")`.

Comment: I'm getting an "Invalid qualifier" error and it's highlighting the ".Column" in the code: Rng.Column.AutoFilter Field:=CDate(9 / 1 / 2021)

Comment: @SJK you need to set `CMDate` as `Criteria`:
`.Rng.Column.AutoFilter _
 Field:=1, _
 Criteria1:=CMDate, _
 VisibleDropDown:=False`

though the `Criteria` type is `Variant` but it needs `string`
[Range.AutoFilter method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofilter)

Comment: @FaneDuru what if his cells are stored as general text format and he can use it as string?

Comment: This approach is, at least, strange. Filtering by a string, will obtain a completely different result. He is clearly asking about filtering on a date, but he does not know how to do it.

Comment: @FaneDuru I don't have a sample of what he works on, but I **think** it should work not as a string but also as a Date. I found [THIS](https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/filter-dates/) which used almost exactly what I said. but I hope it works for him.

Comment: @iѕєρєня The column is a Date column. Can someone post the code with the filter?

Comment: @SJK I'm trying to make a thing, just give me some time :D

Comment: @iѕєρєня I appreciate the help! You all are awesome!

Comment: @SJK `CDate("9/1/2021")` is different than `CDate(9 / 1 / 2021)`. The way you tried really does not make sense.

Comment: @FaneDuru the fact is, `AutoFilter` doesn't handle a date as a variable well enough, that's why we used `AdvancedFilter`. this way the input value won't be hardcoded and used as a variable.